# Handling Future onSuccess as response from an Akka actor

Tags: java, akka

This is the code that works. It send a message to an Actor (Greeter) and wait for the answer back.
But it blocks the current thread.

```
public class Future1Blocking {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("system");
        final ActorRef actorRef = system.actorOf(Props.create(Greeter.class), "greeter");

        Timeout timeout = new Timeout(Duration.create(5, "seconds"));
        Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(actorRef, Greeter.Msg.GREET, timeout);

        // this blocks current running thread
        Greeter.Msg result = (Greeter.Msg) Await.result(future, timeout.duration());

        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

What is the possible way for my example to use `future.onSuccess` to get the result without blocking the current calling thread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ahh. that's was easy (sorry).

```
future.onSuccess(new PrintResult<Object>(), system.dispatcher());
```

Where:

```
public final class PrintResult<T> extends OnSuccess<T> {
    @Override public final void onSuccess(T t) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```